# Создание треугольника в tkiner

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Как нарисовать треугольник с помощью модуля _tkinter python

Comment: сам треугольник нарисовать невозможно. можно только нарисовать многоугольник в виде треугольника

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, вот функция :

```py
from tkinter import *

canvas_width = 200
canvas_height =200
python_green = "#476042" # ID цвета обводки.

master = Tk()

w = Canvas(master, 
           width=canvas_width, 
           height=canvas_height)
w.pack()

points = [0,0,canvas_width,canvas_height/2, 0, canvas_height]
w.create_polygon(points, outline=python_green, 
            fill='yellow', width=3)

mainloop()
```

Можете адаптировать ее к вашему коду изменяя координаты.

Comment: Мой ответ помог?

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Ma3rX Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132135/room-for---3-8-and-ma3rx).